# Wasing the saying of speaking the what?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, the-final-empire

At one point, the crew starts speaking in eastern street slang (known as High Imperial in later Mistborn eras) to annoy Breeze. Aside from Dockson who is speaking gibberish, do we know what they are saying?

Here is the conversation. I have emphasised the eastern street slang:

> Spook rushed over and fetched Breeze a cup of wine.
>
> “He’s such a fine lad,” Breeze noted, accepting the drink. “I barely even have to nudge him Allomantically. If only the rest of you ruffians were so accommodating.”
>
> Spook frowned. **“Niceing the not on the playing without.”**
>
> “I have no idea what you just said, child,” Breeze said. “So I’m simply going to pretend it was coherent, then move on.”
>
> Kelsier rolled his eyes. **“Losing the stress on the nip,”** he said. **“Notting without the needing of care.”**
>
> **“Riding the rile of the rids to the right,”** Spook said with a nod.
>
> “What are you two babbling about?” Breeze said testily.
>
> **“Wasing the was of brightness,”** Spook said. **“Nip the having of wishing of this.”**
>
> **“Ever wasing the doing of this,”** Kelsier agreed.
>
> **“Ever wasing the wish of having the have,”** Ham added with a smile. **“Brighting the wish of wasing the not.”**
>
> Breeze turned to Dockson with exasperation. “I believe our companions have finally lost their minds, dear friend.”
>
> Dockson shrugged. Then, with a perfectly straight face, he said, **“Wasing not of wasing is.”**
>
> Breeze sat, dumbfounded, and the room burst into laughter. Breeze rolled his eyes indignantly, shaking his head and muttering about the crew’s gross childishness.
>   <sub>Mistborn: The Final Empire - Chapter 24</sub>

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sanderson posted a large number of annotations and musings for the original Mistborn trilogy on his website.  On this segment [he says the following](https://brandonsanderson.com/annotation-mistborn-chapter-twenty-four-part-one/):

> If you hate Spook’s dialect, I apologize for this chapter. This is the place in the book where I spent the most time on it. I really like some of the phrases here–I tried to make the dialect focus on rhythm and sounds, making it alliterative and interesting simply to say out-loud. In case you need it, here’s a loose translation of the exchange in this chapter:
>
> Spook: “It’s not nice to play with people like that.”
>   Kelsier: “Oh, don’t worry about what he does to you. He’s not worth your concern.”
>   Spook: “You’re probably right.”
>   Breeze: “What are you two babbling about?”
>   Spook: “He wants to be clever. He pushes people around because he wants to prove that he is clever.”
>   Kelsier “He’s always been like that.”
>   Ham “He’s insecure. I think he worries that he’s really not that clever.”